# Saving annotations to firebase?

Tags: ios, core-data, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I'm using Apple's MapKit and Firebase as the backend. I want to know how to save annotations once a user adds a pin to the map with Firebase. I want the pins to be persistent where once a user opens the map they can see other user's pins and their own. I've found tutorials on how to do it with CoreData but seeing as this app is not just for one user I don't think that it will work like that.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate Geofire as well as FirbaseDatabase into your project. Geofire allows you to save users inputted annotation in the FirebaseDatabase with some methods. 
Read their documentation here https://github.com/firebase/geofire  and hopefully you will find what you want.